# Javascript Maths Node Red Thermistor Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

have node-red running with arduino analogue output through serial to pi, where I'm collecting thermistor data as a msg payload on change.

Trying to turn the Arduino signal into a Temperature - it's the most common 10K enamelised thermistor that adafruit sell. So quite useful code.

The issue is that I am a total noob at JS.

Here's my code so far - using a function node - and trying to replicate the steinhart equation (https://learn.adafruit.com/thermistor/using-a-thermistor)

```
 var input = { payload: msg.payload };
var R0 = 10000;
var R = R0 / ((1023 / input)-1);
var T0 = 273 + 25;
var B = 3950;
var T =  1 / ( (1/T0) + (1/B) * Math.log(R/R0) );
return T;
```

Comment: You cannot divide a number (`1023`) by an object (`input`). You need to access the property of the object that contains the value you want to perform the computation with.

Comment: what does the `msg.payload` return? is it a number?

Comment: thanks - that makes sense - yes it's always a number. Analogue value from the thermistor pin

Comment: ok. added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure whether will `msg.payload` will return number in an actual datatype "Number" meaning or a string that will be a numeric, but something like this should take care of any anomalies when trying to divide strings

```
var numInput = Number(msg.payload);
var R0 = 10000;
var R = R0 / ((1023 / input)-1);
var T0 = 273 + 25;
var B = 3950;
var T =  1 / ( (1/T0) + (1/B) * Math.log(R/R0) );
return T;
```

EDIT: this should fix the errors:

```
var numInput = Number(msg.payload);
var R0 = 10000;
var R = R0 / ((1023 / numInput)-1);
var T0 = 273 + 25;
var B = 3950;
var T =  1 / ( (1/T0) + (1/B) * Math.log(R/R0) );
msg.payload = T;
return msg;
```

Comment: awesome thanks - I went to edit line 3 in your answer to numImput but wouldn;t let me change 

This looks right, thankyou.

When running i get "undefined" - I wonder if my use of * Mathlog() is allowed, or should I break into another var upstream

Comment: where do you get undefined? the variable `T` was? if you get undefined there that probably means the msg.payload had nothing in it, or had something more than a number in it. does your platform have something like a logger? could you do `console.log(msg)` to see what's actually in it?

Comment: Gotcha - yeh it's running in NR so hard to do web-like stuff like console log AFAIK. Think you were right - msg.payload simplified to msg only.

Now delivers a blank (nothing).

I tried this: 

var numInput = Number(msg);
return msg;

And returns the number injected

Tried 

var numInput = Number(msg);
return numInput;

Returns nothing - 

Yet var numInput = msg;
return numInput;

returns number correctly in debug window.

Using the numInput var though, subsequent code does not return T

Comment: There are some typo's in the example, I've edited it to work

Comment: damn, sorry, my bad, i have not rewritten `input` to `numInput` in the example code, thanks @hardillb !

Comment: @hardillb: You should rather fix the actual code, not *add* another version. What good is the "broken" example?